# grails 3.2 rest api, new records do not list

Tags: grails

So I have a rest server from grails 3.2. This happens in development mode and as a jar under tomcat. The application is initialised with data.

Using curl

```
C:\Temp\curl>curl http://centos64:8080/heroes
[{"id":1,"name":"Mr. Nice"},{"id":2,"name":"Narco"},{"id":3,"name":"Bombasto"},{"id":4,"name":"Celeritas"},{"id":5,"name":"Magneta"},{"id":6,"name":"RubberMan"},{"id":7,"name":"Dynama"},{"id":8,"name":"Dr IQ"},{"id":9,"name":"Magma"},{"id":10,"name":"Tornado"}]
```

Add a new entry

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"name\":\"batman\"}"  http://centos64:8080/heroes
{"id":14,"name":"batman"}
```

Confirm that entry

```
C:\Temp\curl>curl http://centos64:8080/heroes/14
{"id":14,"name":"batman"}
```

List all again

```
C:\Temp\curl>curl http://centos64:8080/heroes
[{"id":1,"name":"Mr. Nice"},{"id":2,"name":"Narco"},{"id":3,"name":"Bombasto"},{"id":4,"name":"Celeritas"},{"id":5,"name":"Magneta"},{"id":6,"name":"RubberMan"},{"id":7,"name":"Dynama"},{"id":8,"name":"Dr IQ"},{"id":9,"name":"Magma"},{"id":10,"name":"Tornado"}]
```

Note that batman is not in this list.

Bootstrap.groovy

```
import heroes2.Hero

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        new Hero(name: 'Mr. Nice').save()
    new Hero(name: "Narco").save()
        new Hero(name: "Bombasto").save()
        new Hero(name: "Celeritas").save()
        new Hero(name: "Magneta").save()
        new Hero(name: "RubberMan").save()
        new Hero(name: "Dynama").save()
        new Hero(name: "Dr IQ").save()
        new Hero(name: "Magma").save()
        new Hero(name: "Tornado").save()
        new Hero(name: "Iron Man").save()
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Hero.groovy

```
package heroes2

import grails.rest.*

@Resource(uri = '/heroes', readOnly = false, formats = ['json', 'xml'])
class Hero {
    String name
}
```

UrlMappings.groovy

> package heroes2
>
> class UrlMappings {
>
> ```
> static mappings = {
>     delete "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"delete")
>     get "/$controller(.$format)?"(action:"index")
>     get "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"show", method: "OPTIONS")
>     post "/$controller(.$format)?"(action:"save")
>     put "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"update")
>     patch "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"patch")
>
>     "/"(controller: 'application', action:'index')
>     "500"(view: '/error')
>     "404"(view: '/notFound')
> } }
> ```

Does anyone have any ideas why?

Regards,
John

Comment: You have not shown any of your code. It is difficult to say what is going wrong without knowing what your application is doing.

Comment: There is not much code - grails generated virtually all of it. I will add the domain class to the above and the Bootstrap code. Is there anything more that you need?

Comment: its quite possible that when you called save() method on the domain instance, you flush the session. use save(flush:true) method on your domain instance where ever you are saving new data (it could be your controller or service method)

Comment: Hi @elixir, tried flushing and made no difference. I was thinking along the same lines but equally, would have thought that the framework would include this. This is basic stuff so I must be doing something wrong even though simply using defaults and allow framework to generate everything.

Comment: I do not know the answer but I do now know a better question. The save is fine, the problem is there is a limit of 10 records that grails is returning. I had 10 records in bootstrap, so adding more did not show these in subsequent lists.

Answer (score 0):

The default for index in grails is 10, if want more than 10 then use
centos64:8080/heroes?max=15 will get 15